# Create new column that is a count of how many entries in a row satisfy a condition for each row of a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working with time-series data that summarizes usage of a product by users (each user is a column and each date is a row). I am trying to summarize percent of users adopting this product into their life, which requires they use it for a certain amount of time each day.

```
date          user1         user2           user3              user4
2017-06-23    120.000000    200.000000      20.000000          0.000000   
2017-06-24    201.000000    195.000000      10.000000          0.000000   
2017-06-25    267.333333    190.000000      56.666667          0.000000   
2017-06-26    255.500000    142.500000      42.500000          0.000000   
2017-06-27    269.200000    131.800000      45.600000          0.000000   
2017-06-28    241.500000    138.333333      49.500000          0.000000   
2017-06-29    224.000000    118.571429      61.000000          0.000000
```

I am trying count the number of times the condition is satisfied for each entry in a row and create a new column that counts this and is divided by the total number of users*100. I've tried:

```
df['Percent of Adoption'] = (df[df.columns > 50].count(axis=0)/len(df.columns))*100
```

This yields the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Desired output:

```
date          user1         user2           user3              user4//     
2017-06-23    120.000000    200.000000      20.000000          0.000000   
2017-06-24    201.000000    195.000000      10.000000          0.000000   
2017-06-25    267.333333    190.000000      56.666667          0.000000   
2017-06-26    255.500000    142.500000      42.500000          0.000000   
2017-06-27    269.200000    131.800000      45.600000          0.000000   
2017-06-28    241.500000    138.333333      49.500000          0.000000   
2017-06-29    224.000000    118.571429      61.000000          0.000000 

Percent of Adoption
50.0
50.0
75.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
75.0
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Always add example dataframe and expected output, people want to read data and not read through a lot of text

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered your question based upon the verbiage. But my answers don't match your percent answers. So either I misunderstand, or you're using dummy variables.

First set the index to date.

```
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Then filter the dataframe for values greater than 50 and sum across columns (axis=1), then divide by the count of columns.

```
df['percent_of_adoption'] = (df > 50).sum(axis = 1).div(df.count(axis = 1)) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me. I was using dummy variables since it is confidential data.